# RegEx for matching a string before a year

Tags: regex, string, bash, tcl

I have directory names with include year numbers. I want to split them to variables what is before the year number:

#### Input:

```
Holidays.uS.2019.bla.bla
Holidays.ca.old.2017.bla.bla
Holidays.2015.bla.bla.bla
Holidays.1.2.3.4.at.old.1999.bla.bla.bla.bla
```

The year is not always in the same place, but, it always has 4 digits.

I always need everything up to the year.

For an input:

```
Holidays.ca.old.2017.bla.bla
```

#### Output:

```
Holidays.ca.old
```

#### Attempt

```
set name Holidays.ca.old.2017.bla.bla
set numbers [regexp -all -inline {[0-9]+} $name]
```

Output from my code is the year number, and sometimes other wrong numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/vchKvO/1) might help you to design one:

```
([\w\.]+)(\.[0-9]{4}.+)
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph displays how it would work:

[image]

#### Code:

```
set string "Holidays.1.2.3.4.at.old.1999.bla.bla.bla.bla"
set match [regsub {([\w\.]+)(\.[0-9]{4}.+)} $string "\\1"]
puts $match
```

#### Output

```
Holidays.1.2.3.4.at.old
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regex to match a dot followed with 4 digits that are not followed with a word char, and then matching any other char 0 or more times, and remove the matched text using `regsub` like this:

```
regsub {\.[0-9]{4}\y.*} $name ""
```

See [Tcl demo online](https://ideone.com/ym0Y77):

```
set name "Holidays.ca.old.2017.bla.bla"
set res [regsub {\.[0-9]{4}\y.*} $name ""]
puts $res
# => Holidays.ca.old
```

**Regex details**

- `\.` - a dot
- `[0-9]{4}` - four digits
- `\y` - a word boundary
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars as many as possible.

If you want to see a demo of the regex at regex101.com, you need to replace `\y` with `\b`, see [this demo here](https://regex101.com/r/zrjrxy/2).

Answer (score 0):

`(\w|\.)+(?=\.\d{4})`

**Breakdown**:

- `(\w|\.)+` One or more words (which includes digits) or literal periods.
- `(?=\.\d{4})` Positive lookahead for a literal period followed by exactly four digits.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vaofyC/6

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your help, that's really nice

I use this in tcl and working perfekt forme

```
set name_split [regsub {\.[0-9]{4}\y.*} $name ""]
```

I still need it for a bash script, how can use it?

this does not really work :(

```
name_split=$(echo $name | {\.[0-9]{4}\y.*}
```